# I want to add all my numbers in a array. I wrote a function with in it I wrote a for loop that is not working. for(let p = 0;p <= d.length; p++)

Tags: javascript

I want to add all my numbers in an array. I wrote a function within it I wrote a for loop that is not working. this is the code that is not working

```
for(let p = 0;p <= d.length; p++).
```

```js
function addUp(num) {
  let d = [];
  let m = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    d.push(i)
  }
  for (let p = 0; p <= d.length; p++) {
    m += d[p]
  }

  return m;

}
console.log(addUp(10))
```

Comment: Change the for loop condition to `p < d.length`. If not, you are adding `undefined` to m which is making it `NaN`.

Comment: You might want to look at [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), which can be solved arithmetically using `(n(n+1))/2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, you could optimize your code a bit, here's an example

```js
function addUp(num) {
  let m = 0
  while (num-- > 0) m += num
  return m;
}
console.log(addUp(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `p <= d.length`, but it should be `p < d.length`. This is needed because `p` is initalized to 0.

```js
function addUp(num) {
  let d = [];
  let m = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    d.push(i)
  }
  for (let p = 0; p < d.length; p++) {
    m += d[p]
  }

  return m;

}
console.log(addUp(10))
```